# API. How to handle the keysecret / keypublic / apikey in an app script (gSheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this script that I use to get a token.

```
function makeHttpPostRequestWithAppsScript() {
    const url = "https://clientapi.portfoliopersonal.com/api/1.0/Account/LoginApi?source=web&foo=bar";
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "AuthorizedClient": "API_CLI_REST",
            "ClientKey": "xxxxxxxx",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "ApiKey": "xxxxxxxxx=",
            "ApiSecret": "xxxxxxxx",
      "data": "",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
    "muteHttpExceptions":true,
    });

    Logger.log("Response code is %s", response.getResponseCode());
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

2 questions.

First, is there a way to make the keys not visible? (For security).

The second, the token that this api gives me lasts very little, I think 30 minutes. What I was doing was copying and pasting the token manually into the scripts I needed to use, but this isn't useful.

Can the token be saved somewhere (a file?) so I read it and save it there, every time it changes, automatically?

Would this be appropriate?

Comment: Perhaps you should  read about  [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Comment: @Cooper Thaniks. I see, i can use that for save values, but what about security? I mean, if somebody get access to my google account they could see in plain text the value paired with the key, in the script propierties. There is a way to avoid that? Thanks.

Comment: [Is properties service secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782875/is-propertiesservice-in-google-apps-script-secure)